# how to pass a parameter to a sql script from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rds, python-db-api

I am trying to pass the parameter to the SQL script from python.

below is the script I am trying; please let me know what I am doing wrong here...

```
#!./bin/python
_author_='Mohammed'

import boto3
import cx_Oracle
import sys

con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@localhost:1521/DBName')
print con.version
cur=con.cursor()
statements = open('$location/test.sql').read().format('localhost')
cur.execute(statements)
query_result=cur.fetchall()
for res in query_result:
print(res)
```

************Error***********

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$location\test1.py", line 19, in <module>
    statements = open('$location/test.sql').read().format('localhost')
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: cx_Oracle (and other language APIs such as node-oracledb) let you execute one SQL statement at a time.  These APIs do not do batch-script execution.  You need to split your statements up in Python (or store them in some other separate way) and then pass them one at a time to cx_Oracle's cur.execute().  You may also be able to use PL/SQL to do things like: begin
  execute immediate 'create user testuser identified by testuserpwd';
  execute immediate 'grant connect, create session to testuser';
 end;

Comment: can we use subprocess do it..

Comment: I prefer doing it all natively in Python because then you have better error control.